# ngDialog templateUrl not working when code is minifed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, url

I am using ngDialog in a project, and when the code is not minified, in development, this piece of code works just fine:

```
ngDialog.open({
 template: '/static/scripts/modules/vote/Dialog.html',
            controller: 'DialogCtrl',
            scope: scope
 });
```

But, when the code is minified, I get this error:

```
GET http://pageUrl/static/scripts/modules/vote/Dialog.html 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems that the app can't access the html file, but why then does it work when code is not minified?

Comment: 404 error. Check the file in path `http://pageUrl/static/scripts/modules/vote/Dialog.html`

Comment: It exists. As I said, it works when the code is not minified.

Answer (score 0):

try with this
ngDialog
                .open({
                    template : 'comment',
                    className : 'ngdialog-theme-flat ngdialog-theme-custom',
                    scope : $scope
                });